# is it real to make css grid rows with different and unexpected height?

Tags: css, css-grid

How to make this example with css grid?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9QKO.jpg)

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community.

Comment: You can take a look at column CSS : example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zYYBeRY or flex + js to make it responsive : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aboRWRe (JS forked )